# SQL insert into table by select from dual table

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

Given the following create table SQL (which works fine):

```
CREATE TABLE blah (CAT, BUSINESS_NR, TIME_A, VERSION, SOME_CODE) AS
SELECT 'ABC',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2009-02-19 00:00:00 UTC',    1,  'OPP' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   357,    TIMESTAMP '2020-08-16 00:00:00 UTC',    4,  'FFF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   357,    TIMESTAMP '2020-10-16 00:00:00 UTC',    5,  'ZZZ' FROM DUAL;
```

I have to switch now to an insert stmt, because table blah is created already.

My approach:

```
INSERT INTO blah (CAT, BUSINESS_NR, TIME_A, VERSION, SOME_CODE) 
select 
(         
SELECT 'ABC',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2009-02-19 00:00:00 UTC',    1,  'OPP' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   357,    TIMESTAMP '2020-08-16 00:00:00 UTC',    4,  'FFF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   357,    TIMESTAMP '2020-10-16 00:00:00 UTC',    5,  'ZZZ' FROM DUAL
) from dual;
```

failed with error:

ORA-00913

What could I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a *subquery* as a selected column, which is allowed, but the subquery must return only *one row*  and *one column*.

So this is a valid syntax

```
select 
( SELECT 'ABC'  FROM DUAL ) 
from dual
```

But your subquery returns three rows and  five column, which is not acceptable and leads to  `ORA-00913: too many values`

What you may do is to use the subquery in the `FROM` clause. This is valid syntax:

```
INSERT INTO blah (CAT, BUSINESS_NR, TIME_A, VERSION, SOME_CODE) 
select * 
FROM
(         
SELECT 'ABC',   123,    TIMESTAMP '2009-02-19 00:00:00 UTC',    1,  'OPP' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   357,    TIMESTAMP '2020-08-16 00:00:00 UTC',    4,  'FFF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI',   357,    TIMESTAMP '2020-10-16 00:00:00 UTC',    5,  'ZZZ' FROM DUAL
);
```

In this simple case (as pointed out by others) you may get rid of the main query at all.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the extra `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO blah (CAT, BUSINESS_NR, TIME_A, VERSION, SOME_CODE)         
    SELECT 'ABC', 123, TIMESTAMP '2009-02-19 00:00:00 UTC', 1, 'OPP' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'GHI', 357, TIMESTAMP '2020-08-16 00:00:00 UTC', 4, 'FFF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'GHI', 357, TIMESTAMP '2020-10-16 00:00:00 UTC', 5, 'ZZZ' FROM DUAL;
```

The problem with your query is that you have subqueries that return more than one column.  That is not generally allowed in SQL.